# Cursor update row operator

Tags: arcpy, cursor

This is a find and replace script I have been working on. I feel I am very close, as the script does everything but actually change the values, leading me to believe there is an operator issue. I have been using == as you can see, but have also tried = when the cursor looks for oldText only to get a syntax error. Any thoughts?

```
import arcpy

FC = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
targetField = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
oldText = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)
replaceText = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(3)


fields = arcpy.ListFields(FC)


queryString = queryString = targetField + ' = ' + oldText
print queryString
arcpy.AddMessage(queryString)


try:

    with arcpy.da.UpdateCursor(FC, (targetField), queryString) as cursor:
        for field in fields:
            if field.name == targetField and field.type == 'String':
                for row in cursor:
                    if row[0] == str(oldText):
                        row[0] = str(replaceText)
                    cursor.updateRow(row)

        elif field.name == targetField and field.type == 'Single':
             for row in cursor:
                if row[0] == float(oldText):
                    row[0] = float(replaceText)
                    cursor.updateRow(row)

        elif field.name == targetField and field.type == 'Integer':
             for row in cursor:
                if row[0] == int(oldText):
                    row[0] = int(replaceText)
                    cursor.updateRow(row)




        arcpy.AddMessage("String where " + oldText + " found and replaced with " + replaceText)



except:
        arcpy.AddMessage \(arcpy.GetMessages())
        arcpy.AddError("Failed to find and replace where " + queryString)
```

Comment: I think you will find debugging Python much easier if you dispense with try/except statements while testing, and in any code snippets posted here, because they mask the errors that Python provides to help you.  Also, include copious `print` statements to make sure that your variables are set to what you think they are all the way through.

Comment: Indent your elif statements.

Comment: Ditto what Tom said. Indent your elif statements. Also, you really don't need to test if row[0] == oldText. The cursor via queryString is only pulling rows where the oldText condition is met, so trust your cursor to do the filtering. If the cursor is not pulling the desired rows, then the problem is in your original SQL statement. See my answer to your other question (http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/184754/56700) to troubleshoot possible issues with the SQL statement.